# Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to a backup of sudo does not work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, ubuntu-16.04

I've accidentally removed the contents of the `/usr` folder, but I have a backup of it in `/mnt/usr`.

To fix it I need `sudo`, but it was in `/usr/bin`. So I tried to use `/mnt/usr/bin/sudo`, but it throws a linker error:

`/mnt/usr/bin/sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libsudo_util.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I tried to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/usr/lib/sudo /mnt/usr/bin/sudo ls
```

but the same error still appears.

Can anybody help me to recover my system?

Comment: Can you log in as root user? Alternatively: Use a live distribution to fix it. Or: Set `$PATH` variable: `PATH=$PATH:/mnt/usr/bin`

Comment: @confetti, using live distribution is not possible because it is remote server installation. Root user access maybe could be used, I've asked colleagues for it. PATH does not helped, same linker error.

Comment: Okay I just realized that all your libraries are missing too, at first I thought just the binaries were affected. Unless you can't get into a recovery system or shell I *think* gaining root might be your only chance. It should be possible to create a link from /usr/ to /mnt/usr/ and remove it once the copying is done, but someone with a bigger expertise on this has to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` needs to point to where the shared libraries are, `/mnt/usr/libexec/sudo/:/mnt/lib64` maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by restoring server from backup